# Django: Unable to connect to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django, freetds

I am unable to connect to the MS SQL server using Django (Version- 1.11.3)

Here is the error, I seem to be getting:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', u'[08001]
>   [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

This is the odbcinst.ini file:

```
 [FreeTDS] 
 Description=TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
 Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
 Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so 
 CPTimeout= 
 CPReuse=
 UsageCount=2
```

This is the django settings.py snippet:

```
DATABASES = {
    'mssql': {
        'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<NAME>',
        'USER': '<USER>',
        'PASSWORD':'<password>',
        'HOST':'<host-id>',
        'OPTIONS':
        {
            'driver':'FreeTDS'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated by the django docs: https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

I've used pyodbc in python applications, but never in django.

Comment: @Jaberwocky I tried that approach. 

Getting the following error: 
  File ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You'll need to set the connection name as `default` instead of `mssql`
- If you're using FreeTDS on Linux, I'd recommend using the `django-pyodbc-azure` Django DB engine: `pip install 'django-pyodbc-azure>=1.11,<2'`
- You'll need to specify the TDS Verison in your settings.

The upshot of this will be settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<NAME>',
        'USER': '<USER>',
        'PASSWORD':'<password>',
        'HOST':'<host-id>',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'unicode_results': True,
            'host_is_server': True,
            'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.3',
        }
    }
}
```

For windows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<NAME>',
        'USER': '<USER>',
        'PASSWORD':'<password>',
        'HOST':'<host-id>',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the `django-pyodbc-azure` docs for 1.11 here: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/tree/azure-1.11

Good luck! These settings can be tricky for SQL Server, but once you get them right, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while working on Windows 10 and here's what worked for me:
Download the driver from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
And then add 'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', to Options in settings.py
I hope it helps.